# Remove or add trailing slash from CakePHP 2.x on Apache using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I am trying to enforce the removal or add of trailing slashes to my CakePHP 2.x app using the following inside the .htaccess located at `/app/webroot`.

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteEngine On
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
#</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Add trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

**or** the following for add the trailing slash.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

But I don't want to enforce the domain as it could be running locally or inside a subfolder. How do I fix this? All the docs I've read online seem to enforce the FULL url of the app.

**In fact even if I use the FULL url it still doesn't work. Has anyone managed to get this working with CakePHP? Seems you MUST run it through the index.php file**

**To clarify I'm looking for a solution for ADDING and REMOVING trailing slashes in CakePHP without having to hardcode the url into the .htaccess file.**

Comment: Can you provide example like this url to that url, if possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  If you enter trailing slashes in the URL, cake will by default remove them and show the correct page.
Are you trying to remove trailing slashes from the urls generated by the HTMLHelper or Router?

Comment: Cake doesn't remove them! If I type in `http://domain.com/posts/` or `http://domain.com/posts` both will work and the first does not remove the trailing slash so the page is accessible at BOTH urls. I want to make it so that the trailing slash is removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is usually not a complicated thing.

What about this ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   # if this is an existing folder/file then leave
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule . - [L]

   # if trailing slash then redirect to url without trailing slash
   RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

   # internal rewrite to controller/dispatcher index.php
   RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If this one is not working, well this could be a problem on your side.
Did you already use mod_rewrite before ? Is it enabled ?

---

EDIT: if your website is not in root folder (`DOCUMENT_ROOT`) you have 2 options. You could put your htaccess in `application` folder or in root folder.

I suggest you to put your htaccess in your `application` folder (dedicated for your website only). Otherwise, the code would not be exactly the same. Here's the code in this case:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /application/

   # if this is an existing folder/file then leave
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule . - [L]

   # if trailing slash then redirect to url without trailing slash
   RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

   # internal rewrite to controller/dispatcher index.php
   RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

---

Your second question:

> Also what would be the code for ENFORCING a trailing slash?

You could handle that with this code (only one line changed)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /application/

   # if this is an existing folder/file then leave
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule . - [L]

   # if no trailing slash then redirect to url with trailing slash
   RewriteRule ^/?(.+)([^/])$ $1$2/ [R=301,L]

   # internal rewrite to controller/dispatcher index.php
   RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Removing the `/` before the index.php loads the site but it doesn't do anything with the slashes except redirect me back to the root of the sever (e.g. if I run it locally at `localhost:8888/application/posts/` it will redirect to `localhost:8888/posts`) NOTE this ONLY happens if I put the trailing slash ON. And it's not handling the subfolder `application`.

Comment: Doing this works: `RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/application/$1 [R=301,L]` but can I get around having to code in the app folder?

Comment: Also what would be the code for ENFORCING a trailing slash? Thanks.

Comment: The `application` folder issue can be solved. You have to define a `RewriteBase` or you could do it directly in rule definitions. I will update my answer with that point and also with how to enforce a trailing slash

Comment: Cool thanks. I can't move the .htaccess file, due to the way in which CakePHP works. But adding the rewrite base is fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Gives me the error: The requested URL /cavrn/app/webroot/posts/ was not found on this server. So it needs to route through that index.php file inside the webroot which is in the original rewrite rules.

Comment: I am sorry but me does not understand what does not work or I understood your problem from the beginning... :-/

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([bakery](http://bakery.cakephp.org/%20articles/view/4caea0e1-0e48-4b55-a9ce-46a082f0cb67)):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

If you want to do it for SEO you always have an option to use canonical links and stop bother about redirects:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/your_controller/action/"/>
```

Comment: Same as what @:Georgio posted, which doesn't work. It seems you MUST have index.php in the rule otherwise it ends up redirecting you to the webroot folder of the app. Any ideas?

Comment: What about RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]?