# Routing: Add '/' to the end of the address

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP version 3.0 to build a web application.

routing.php generates urls like: /plugin/controller

Wish to the address to always have a '/' at the end of the address.

Like: /plugin/controller/

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can simply edit the .htaccess to achieve this. See [this CakePHP 2.x question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270633/remove-or-add-trailing-slash-from-cakephp-2-x-on-apache-using-htaccess), it still works the same in 3.0.

Comment: If you want that, create and use your own routing class that enforces it. @Oldskool - viable, but that would mean all links are a 301 hop; hardly efficient.

Comment: Either way...I just need it to be consistent

Comment: It should be consistent (without trailing slash) if you use the `HtmlHelper`'s `link()` method for all your links.

Comment: In what cases is it not being consistent for you?